# make turtles move on patches with specific attributes

Tags: netlogo

I'm having some trouble with my netlogo model and I was hoping someone might be able to help me get through it.

I have a world with patch with specific attributes that represents parks, buildings, streets (2 types small and large), etc. I want my turtles to move towards a specific point (I managed to do that). But I'd like the turtles to move only on patches representing the streets, the have attributes specific to them, the color blue and a value 3 or 4. Is thee a way to do that ?

Here is how I set up my world :

```
extensions  
[
  gis   
]


globals    
[
  Batiments
  ChemindeFer
  Cimetiere
  Densite
  Eau
  Ponts
  Routes
  TerrainSports
  Vegetations
]


patches-own 
[
  Cheminferroviaire
  Bati
  pont
  TerraindeSport
  Vege
  cimetary
  water
  road
  densitepop
  Npatchvert

]


breed [ Renards renard]
breed [ Proies proie]


Renards-own
[
  stress
  poids
]


Proies-own
[
  weight
]


to setup          
ca                
  initialiserGIS  
  creerRenard
  creerProie
  move
reset-ticks

end



  to initialiserGIS            


  ; ---------------------- chargement densité ----------------------------

  set Densite gis:load-dataset "desite_ind_g.asc"
  gis:apply-raster Densite densitepop

  let min-Densite gis:minimum-of Densite
  let max-Densite gis:maximum-of Densite
   ask patches
  [
    ifelse densitepop >= 1.5
    [ set pcolor scale-color grey densitepop 1.5 6]
    [ set pcolor white ]
  ]


  ;------------------- chargement des chemin de fer ----------------

  set ChemindeFer gis:load-dataset "chdefer_g.asc"
  gis:apply-raster ChemindeFer Cheminferroviaire
  ask patches with [Cheminferroviaire = 1]
  [set pcolor grey]


   ;--------------------- chargement batiments --------------------

  set Batiments gis:load-dataset "batiment_g.asc"
  gis:apply-raster Batiments Bati
  ask patches with [Bati = 1]
  [set pcolor brown]


   ;--------------------- chargement des ponts --------------------

  set Ponts gis:load-dataset "ponts_g.asc"
  gis:apply-raster Ponts pont
  ask patches with [ pont = 1]
  [set pcolor 87]

  ;--------------------- chargement de l'eau ----------------------

  set Eau gis:load-dataset "eau_g.asc"
  gis:apply-raster Eau water
  ask patches with [ water = 1]
  [set pcolor blue]

  ;--------------------- sports field -----------------

  set TerrainSports gis:load-dataset "terrain_sport_g.asc"
  gis:apply-raster TerrainSports TerraindeSport
  ask patches with [ TerraindeSport = 1]
  [set pcolor green]

  ;--------------------- végétation --------------------

  set Vegetations gis:load-dataset "vegetation_g.asc"
  gis:apply-raster Vegetations Vege
  ask patches with [ vege = 1 ]
  [set pcolor green]

  ;--------------------- cimetary --------------------

  set Cimetiere gis:load-dataset "cimetiere_g.asc"
  gis:apply-raster Cimetiere cimetary
  ask patches with [ cimetary = 1 ]
  [set pcolor green]

  ;---------------------- roads ---------------------------

  set Routes gis:load-dataset "routes_g.asc"
  gis:apply-raster Routes road

  ask patches with
  [ road = 4] [set pcolor 87]
  ask patches with
  [ road = 3] [set pcolor 104]
  ask patches with
  [ road = 0] [set pcolor green]


end




to creerRenard

  create-Renards 10

end 

to move

  ; --- 1st mouvement (towards campus) --- 
  ask renards 
  [ set heading towardsxy 10 101 
  fd 1 ]
end
```

Comment: Your question says that roads are blue, but your code says that water is blue?

Answer (score 0):

To prevent a turtle from stepping onto anything but a blue patch, you can do:

```
ifelse [pcolor = blue] of patch-ahead 1
  [ fd 1 ]
  [ ...do something else here... ]
```

but you'll need to decide what the "do something else" part is. What do you want to happen in that case...?

Comment: I would like for the turtle to look for the patches that are green since they're what the turtle is aiming for while only moving on blue patches

Comment: okay, but that's only a very vague description. how exactly do you want the turtles to "look for" green patches? that could mean lots of very different things that would result in completely different code.

Comment: I'm fairly new at netlogo so I'm actually not sure how to materialize that, but I was thinking of using something like if patches with pcolor in-radius  10 move-per-tick towards patch

Comment: That sounds vaguely plausible. Sure, take a stab at something like that, and come back and ask a new question if you get stuck, with details on where exactly you got stuck.